# Singleton Pattern performance issue

Tags: c++, singleton

I am reviewing an existing piece of code which uses a LOT of singleton classes and accesses. I am trying to improve the performance of this code.

One thing that comes to mind is to optimize the Singleton::getInstance() piece of code.

Rather than using Singleton::getInstance(), I am inclined to replace this with structure with two calls.

a. A function that would create and prepare the singleton instance, like Singleton::prepareInstance() that would be called once at the start of the subsystem.
b. an inline implementation of getInstance() that would just return the reference without checking if it's valid or not.

Is that a viable solution? Any way to improve on this?

The current Singleton::getInstance() code that I have looks like this

```
Singleton * Singleton::getInstance() {
    if(m_instance == NULL) {
        m_instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return m_instance;
}
```

Is the approach mentioned by πάντα ῥεῖ any faster?

Comment: This sounds like massive premature optimization.  I doubt very much that the performance issues are related to `GetInstance` unless it does something really obscenely stupid! :)

Comment: I doubt that this will have any impact on performance (in terms of execution speed, i presume)

Comment: "... code which uses a LOT of singleton classes and accesses." That's a big red flag right there. I suspect this code has serious design problems.

Comment: @remudada _'Is the approach mentioned by Lea Hayes any faster?'_ I don't see what approach she gives, but mine will definitely be (at least the `NULL` check is eliminated) ;) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The compiler will still generate something similar. I doubt there'd be much performance difference.

Comment: With branch predictions, I suspect that you won't see any difference with or without the `if`.

Comment: It may or may not be faster, but it is has some advantages. Instances will be cleaned up when the program is ended, what is usually not done with the classic getInstance() method. On C++11 it is also guaranteed to be thread-safe. But then, using singletons is often a design flaw (global variables!), so if you can justify it with performance arguments to remove them, do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> b. an inline implementation of getInstance() that would just return the reference without checking if it's valid or not.

Why there's need to check for validity? My singleton `GetInstance()` implementations usually look like this:

```
Singleton& Singleton::instance() {
    static Singleton theInstance;
    return theInstance;
}
```

I doubt such code should have any performance impact, neither it's necessary to check anything for validity.

Comment: Now, this is cool. Let me update the code that I am working with currently . . .

Comment: can this function be safely inlined ?

Comment: @remudada _'can this function be safely inlined ?'_ Should be possible.

Comment: From what I remember, if multiple threads hit the instance() function, this solution is perfectly safe if you're using C++11.  However not so safe if using earlier versions of C++, at least not guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Same issue with the OP's sample code, and there are ways (for both styles) to make them thread safe.

Comment: In C++11 (with Clang and g++ at least, unsure about VC++) this code will emit a check to see if the instance has been initialized (if the initialization isn't trivial) for thread-safety.  It's still not a performance concern, but this is essentially equivalent to the null pointer check in the question.

Answer (score 7):

A proper implementation of `Singleton::getInstance()` shouldn't have any performance issues. Sure the first invocation might be costly (for the initial setup of the singleton instance) but any subsequent invocations should simply return the instance which should be super fast.

> b. an inline implementation of getInstance() that would just return the reference without checking if it's valid or not.

In my view this goes against one of the fundamental concepts of the singleton pattern. `Singleton::getInstance()` should ALWAYS return a valid instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a profiler before you do optimization. It is usually quite revealing where the runtime is spent. In your case, it is very likely not the getInstance method of the singletons, because these will probably be inlined and branch prediction will eliminate the cost for the if-statement. If it turns out to be a performance issue, this will be a good excuse to remove the singletons and improve the architecture. If not, use Meyer's singleton (if multi-threading is a concern, only for C++11).