# Is following singleton implementation thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

Is following singleton implementation thread safe? The ::Instance method should be correct, the Dispose is my own creation so want to make sure I didn't overlooked anything.

```
std::atomic<S *> S::_instance;
std::mutex S::_singleton_mutex;

S& S::Instance()
{
    using namespace std;
    S * tmp = _instance.load(memory_order_relaxed);
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
    if (tmp == nullptr)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> l(_singleton_mutex);
        tmp = _instance.load(memory_order_relaxed);
        if (tmp == nullptr)
        {
            tmp = new S();
            atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
            _instance.store(tmp, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    return *tmp;
}

void S::Dispose()
{
    using namespace std;
    S * tmp = _instance.load(memory_order_relaxed);
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
    if (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> l(_singleton_mutex);
        tmp = _instance.load(memory_order_relaxed);
        if (tmp != nullptr)
        {
            atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
            _instance.store(nullptr, memory_order_relaxed);
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Instance` is the same as the one provided in [Double-checked_locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) and should be correct.

Comment: BTW, deleting null pointer is valid.

Comment: @Jarod42 lol thanks man, I completely forgot about that :D I think it's safe enough to use in my case.. so dispose could be simplified to delete _instance.load(..); ?

Comment: Indeed, I think the second `if (tmp)` is useless.

Comment: The easiest way to get a thread safe singleton is using the implementation as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485432/singleton-pattern-performance-issue/22485728#22485728).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: But that doesn't allow the dispose part.

Comment: Just a comment for some Qt users if they are not aware of it: The [Q_GLOBAL_STATIC](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglobalstatic.html#Q_GLOBAL_STATIC) macro in Qt 5 (was in some versions of 4 actually) creates a global static object 'in a thread-safe manner on all platforms'  (from the docs)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ 1) it doesn't allow dispose part 2) in visual studio it isn't thread safe (don't know about 2015, but 2012 definitely not afaik)

Comment: Why going through all those hurdles instead of simple Meyer's singleton?

Comment: I need to be able to dispose the singleton when needed. Cannot do that with Meyer's singleton. Plus Meyer's singleton is not thread-safe in visual studio 2012 AFAIK.

Comment: @Paladin - correct, it's not thread safe in VS2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is: Yes, looks good.

More Info:

When it is acceptable for you to potentially have two instances for a short moment, where the second one will be destroyed immediately, you can get rid of the mutex:

```
std::atomic<S *> S::_instance;

S& S::Instance()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto tmp = _instance.load(memory_order_relaxed);
    if (tmp == nullptr)
    {
        auto tmp2 = new S();
        if( !_instance.compare_exchange_strong(tmp, tmp2) )
            delete tmp2;
    }
    return *tmp;
}

void S::Dispose()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto tmp = _instance.load(memory_order_relaxed);
    if (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        if( _instance.compare_exchange_strong(tmp, nullptr) )
            delete tmp;
    }
}
```

When two thread start Instance() at the same time, both see a `nullptr` and create a new `S`. Only one of them will successfuly replace the instance pointer, while the other one will immediately delete the new S instead.

Anyway, you might prefer to use Scott Meyers singleton, though it does not provide a way to dispose the object:

```
S& S::Instance() 
{
    // This instance will be created at first call - thread safe.
    // it lives until the program terminates.
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}
```

This is most elegant, minimal code, and thread safe, btw.

Comment: in general I agree, except 1) it doesn't allow disposing of singleton 2) it isn't thread safe in visual studio 2012 afaik, don't know about newer.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the other answers, the implementation seems fine. However, there is a conceptual problem: a race condition between a user and a disposer of the instance.

```
Thread A: var i = s::Instance();
Thread B: s::Dispose();
Thread A: i.doSth();
```

There might be use-cases where you can guarantee this never happens; otherwise,
reference counting might be a solution to this problem.